# Why is there a little nose on the PCIe connector?

Tags: pcb, pcie

PCI express cards have an edge connector with a little notch in it to prevent the card from moving if the socket is longer than the connector.  Additionally, the printed circuit board has a protrusion in front of the actual connector.  What is its purpose?

Depicted below is a PCIe card.  You can clearly see the protrusion I mean to the left of the edge connector.
[image: PCIe card]

*Picture from [Wikimedia Commons](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Datei:Gigabyte_GV-NX62TC256D8_Rev_1.0.jpg) by Clemens PFEIFFER, Vienna.*

Comment: @JCRM Indeed! Sorry for this weird typo.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

According to the PCI Express Card Electromechanical Specification 1.1 it is to prevent insertion into a standard "non-express" PCI socket.

[image: Excerpt from linked document]

http://read.pudn.com/downloads166/ebook/758109/PCI_Express_CEM_1.1.pdf [page 72]